# Call long running method and continue with other tasks

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

```
public class PerformMainTask()
{
    Task1();
    Task2();
    PerformLongTask();
    Task3();
    Task4();
}
```

What I would like to achieve here is to `PerformLongTask()` onto another thread, and to continue with Task3 & Task4 even when `PerformLongTask()` is still running.

How should my `PerformLongTask()` be like in a C# 5.0 way?

Do I need to use `async/await`?

Comment: Go for background threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution I know of is:

```
Task1();
Task2();
var task3 = Task.Run(() => PerformLongTask());
Task4();
Task5();
task3.Wait(); //if task3 has not started yet it will be inlined here
```

Simple and efficient. If you need to propagate errors you should probably use `Parallel.Invoke`:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
 () => { PerformLongTask(); },
 () => { Task4(); Task5(); }
);
```

Comment: Task.Wait will already propagate the exceptions that occured in the task (in an `AggregateException` wrapper)

Comment: Do I remove task3.Wait() if I don't even care if it finishes or not?

Comment: @The8thBit no, hook up a continuation that only fires on error. Log the exception. It might not be doing any work at all due to a bug.

Comment: @usr would you be so kind as to show me how I can do that? Meanwhile, answer marked

Comment: Sure. `task3.ContinueWith(() => LogError(task3.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);`. I really recommend not swallowing any errors or you will find bugs only month later.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using C# 5 and all your Task() methods truly return a `Task` (or anything awaitable), your code should look like that:

```
public async Task PerformMainTask()
{
    await Task1();
    await Task2();
    // Start long task
    var longTask = PerformLongTask();
    await Task3();
    await Task4();
    //wait for long task to finish
    await longTask;
}
```

However, if your long task does not run parallelly on its own, you can force it to do so with `Task.Run`:

```
public async Task PerformMainTask()
{
    await Task1();
    await Task2();
    // Start long task
    var longTask = Task.Run(PerformLongTask);
    await Task3();
    await Task4();
    //wait for long task to finish
    await longTask;
}
```

If none are your tasks are really tasks, just strip all the await except the last one, and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PerformMainTask()
{
    Task1();
    Task2();

    Task.WaitAll(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PerformLongTask()), Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Task3(); Task4(); }));
}
```